# Save elements when using the session Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am trying to use the session with Symfony. 
In fact, I want to complete a form before login. 
 
For this reason, I would like this scheme:

1. Save the different fields in the session
2. Login/register
3. Save in the database

**My controller:**

```
    public function customMadeAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $this->container->get('session');

        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        $CustomMade = new CustomMade();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CustomMadeType(), $CustomMade);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($user === 'anon.') {
            if($form->isValid()) {

                # 1-Save in session
                var_dump($CustomMade); #I have an array with all I need
                $session->set('infos', $CustomMade); #It does not save my informations

                # 2-Redirect to login/register
                $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
                if (!$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
                    throw new AccessDeniedException('Accès refusé');
                } else {

                # 3-Save in database
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($CustomMade);
                $em->flush();
                }
            }
        }else{
            if($form->isValid()) {
                $CustomMade->setIdUser($user->getId());
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($CustomMade);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }
        return $this->render('FrontBundle:Forms:customMade.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the data, save **only** the input **data** from the form (after validation) and not the **entirely entity** (with possibly a lot of... shit, unless that is what you want).

You can just set the object/array into the session and Symfony will take care of serializing and unserializing it for you

If this is the case, replace

```
$session->set('infos', $CustomMade);
```

by

```
$session->set('infos', $form->getData());
```

This way you'll be later simply do:

```
$data = $session->get('infos');
```

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer I guess it works. Can you please give me a link to the docs where it mentions this automatic serialization ? I can't manage to find any.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can store an object in a session.
Here are a few solutions :

1. store manually each field of your object in the session
2. serialize your object and save it in the session
3. store it in the database with a flag saying it is not yet attached to a user, and save the id in session

As I see it, 1 is the fastest to implement, but it will be a pain to maintain if you later add fields to your entity. Solution 2 is better, but the deserialization is not so easy. I think solution 3 is the best, it is not that complicated to implement and will not cause any maintainance issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of Antoine is right,

**You will have to serialize the object** in order to be able to store it in the session.
The easiest way should be using the [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) and **decode your object as json**:

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
$jsonDecoded = $serializer->serialize($doctrineobject, 'json');
```

**Btw.** as stated in the comments this will serialize the whole doctrine structure connected to the entity.
However a toArray() function could be implemented into the entity in order to serialize an array structure only, but this approach becomes very complex when dealing with oneToOne oneToMany and manyToMany relationships

Comment: If you try to serialize a doctrine object, it's mean possibly serialize the entity manager...? except if the serializer do the right job, i don't know

Comment: I found this http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#serializing-entities so yes it's not recomanded

Comment: Thanks for the hint... You are absolutly right its possible but it would indeed serialize the whole entity manager... I will update the answer as soon as i am in front of my pc